# Using DB::table in Laravel Controllers

Tags: php, laravel-4

I'm trying to use the following in my controller then dd() the output but i'm getting the following error:

```
  public function send($id)
  {
     $user_id = Input::get('user')
     $user = DB::table('jobs')
          ->where('id', '=', $id)
          ->and('user_id', $user_id)
          ->get();
      dd($user);
    }
```

Error:

```
Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalErrorException

syntax error, unexpected '$user' (T_VARIABLE)
```

What have I missed or done wrong and how can I do this?

Comment: You forgot a semi colon after the Input::get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a semi colon after ('user'). Change your code to:

```
 public function send($id) { 
    $user_id = Input::get('user'); 
    $user = DB::table('jobs') 
            ->where('id', '=', $id) 
            ->and('user_id', $user_id) 
            ->get(); 
    dd($user); 
}
```

Comment: Doh! What a douche I am! But now the and() doesn't work but I need the query to be where id = $id and user_id = $user_id so how could one do that, as I;m getting this error

Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::and()

Comment: and I figured it out i can user ->where() twice

Comment: instead of ->and you can chain another ->where